# Can't copy and paste keyframes from another action

Tags: animation, dopesheet, actions

I'm trying to copy some range of keyframes to another action.

In same action, copy and paste works fine, but paste to another action doesn't work.

I mean I have plenty bones but only single bone was pasted, even I selected all bones before copy and paste.

[image]
[image]

It happens often to me and it's really quite annoying. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but mostly it works if I select all bones that have keyframes to copy, both dopesheet and 3d view.

However sometimes it's not working even do that, so that's why I said 100% sure.

I still facing this issue sometimes, but mostly works fine and some how it works after do something try to fix, but don't know what exactly fix this.